# Configurar android M para mostrar errores de cierre inesperado en un Huawei

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un teléfono "huawei g play mini" con android 6 pero cuando ejecuto mi aplicación no puedo ver los errores cuando se cierra la aplicación, intente con un "sony" con android 5 y si me muestra los errores en el `LogCat`. He allí el origen de mi pregunta no se si hay alguna opción que he olvidado activar.

Answer (score 2):

Ya he encontrado la solución.
La solución es editar una opción en el funcionamiento del Huawei.

1. Marcar el numero *#*#2846579#*#*.
2. Seleccionar Background Settings.
3. Seleccionar LOG Settings.
4. Marcar CP Log (activar mensajes debug y verbose) y AP Log(Para activar el log general de la aplicacion), en mi caso me basto con el CP Log.
5. Reiniciar el dispositivo.

Comment: Hola Manuel, estaría perfecto si colocas aquí lo que hayas hecho para solucionar tu problema y no colocar el link de otro sitio, de esa manera los usuarios que tengan algo similar puedan resolverla u orientarse con tu respuesta.

Comment: Manuel Couoh, puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta, así se cierra la pregunta como resuelta

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente asegura que los drivers del dispositivo esten instalados; si usas varios dispositivos, en `Android Studio` activa `Android Monitor`, ahí puedes cambiar el dispositivo que deseas, para que imprima los mensajes en el LogCat:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda también configurar el filtro de mensajes en "Verbose" para que muestre todo los tipos.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por los drivers lo he instalado tanto los del fabricante como los genéricos, si tengo seleccionado el dispositivo. Me muestra ciertas entradas del lo pero los errores puntuales como NullPointerException esos no me los muestra en el log si uso otro movil con JB o LP si lo muestra

Comment: Recuerda también configurar el filtro de mensajes en "Verbose" para que muestre todo los tipos. Lo tienes en verbose.

Comment: Así es lo he configurado lo extraño es que si hago el Log desde el codigo si me lo muestra.